# Unable to configure drives on Intel S500VSA server board.

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, raid-1, hardware-raid

I am installing two 2TB SATA drives on an Intel S500VSA server board. I want to configure a RAID 1 array. When I log into the RAID configuration panel with Ctrl-E I find that the two drives are identified but I am unable to configure them. I tried Intel support but the board is no longer supported. I have been all over the Intel website but have found no answer to this problem. From the RAID configuration panel, when I go into Management/Configure/Easy_Configuration the two drives are correctly recognized and appear in the list on port 0 and port 1 but there are no options available to configure anything (it says something like, "no further configuration is necessary"). When I go into Management/Objects/Logical_Drive it says no LDs are currently configured. How can I configure my array? I already did update the BIOS.

Comment: You may need to chance RAID controller mode to actual RAID, not SATA/AHCI.

Comment: It was changed. The option to configure RAID with this BIOS doesn't even display if it's not in RAID mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An existing raid may of been detected - Wipe both partitions with a new partition table on another machine then try again.

Comment: Both drives are brand new and never have been partitioned or used at all.

Comment: Does not mean you shouldn't format them in another machine first - Try it.